# Emailing STDERR and a file after a Java program has run

Tags: java, email, command-line

I needed to create a daily (automatic) email with information about a service I am using.  I wrote a Java program that gathers information from that service and puts it into a `.xls` file.  This Java program also prints diagnostic information to `STDERR`.

I would like to email the `.xls` file as an attachment and have the diagnostic information in the email body.  How can I get this information in the email through the command-line?

Comment: what operating system are you using?  what scripting language?

Comment: Redhat is the operating system. I am able to solve this problem using Perl, however, I am wondering if there is a simpler way with just the commmandline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mail`/`mailx` don't support attachments. If you need attachments, install `mutt`:

```
mutt -s Subject -a file send@to
```

But it can only attach a single file. A workaround would be to send `stderr` as body of the mail:

```
mutt -s Subject -a info.xls send@to < logfile
```

Comment: So would something like `java program.jar 2> mutt -s Java Program -a output.xls` work? (Sorry, I currently do not have access to the box)

Comment: Yes but you should do it in two steps (i.e. without the pipe); `mutt` *should* read the `.xls` file after the body is finished but maybe it checks that the file exists before it even starts. That would also allow you to send the mail again in case of an error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on Unix, you can check the ff command-line utilities:

1. mail
2. mailx

these utilities require an SMTP server for the actual delivery of the messages

more info (sending with attachments) here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-unix-sending-files-as-mail-attachments/

Comment: That's the first time in years I've seen `uuencode` again. Is that still supported by any mail client? :-) I'm not downvoting but I still don't like this answer. PS: They also suggest to use `mutt` and only use `uuencode` if everything else fails.

Comment: Yours is the best answer. So far it's still working. I have to consider using mutt going forward. As for mailx, it supports the -a option for attachments i.e. without using uuencode.